# ¿Cómo puedo añadir una columna a un dataframe que sea la unión de otras dos columnas separadas por "_"?

Tags: r, dataframe

Quiero un dataframe en el que se añada una columna que sea la unión de otras dos separadas con "_". He probado con unite(), pero lo que ocurre es que se unen las dos columnas y me da como resultado un dataframe con solo la columna de la unión. Yo quiero que aparezcan las tres columnas, es decir, las dos con las que hago la unión y la columna de la unión.

Con la siguiente línea de código se crea un dataframe con la columna nombre, y yo quiero un dataframe con la columna nombre, Id y Especie

```
df <- df %>% 
      unite(nombre, c("Id","Especie"),sep = " _ "))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto, el comportamiento de `unite` es el de eliminar las columnas originales y dejar solo la unión, pero esto puede modificarse mediante `remove=FALSE`:

```
df1 %>% 
  unite("nombre", 
        c("Id","Especie"), 
        sep='_', 
        remove=FALSE)
```